# TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 6 were given

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        print("person class is called")


class Teacher:
    def __init__(self,fname,lname):
        self.fname=fname
        self.lname=lname
        print("Techer class is called")


class Student(Person , Teacher):
    def __int__(self,sub,grade,name,fname,lname):
        self.sub=sub
        self.grade=grade
        Person.__init__(self,name)
        Teacher.__init__(self,fname,lname)
        print("student class is called")

    def getdata(self):
        print("subject name:",self.sub,"grade is:",self.grade)
        print("teacher name:",self.fname)


std1=Student("english","7.0","ravi","raj","savaliya")
std1.getdata()
```

Comment: Typo. `__int__` -> `__init__` Check if that fixes it, although I think it would say "takes 1 positional argument" if it was it, because default init takes only self?

Comment: @h4z3 It takes 2 positional arguments because it is inherited from `Person`.

Comment: @MaxiMouse Thanks. The multi-inheritance got me confused there, I didn't know which init gets inherited then. - Person takes 2 arguments, but Teacher gets 3

Comment: @h4z3 You can use `Student.__mro__` to see the method resolution order. It's Student, Person, Teacher, object.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo `__int__` -> `__init__`. Instead of

```
class Student(Person , Teacher):
    def __int__(self,sub,grade,name,fname,lname):
```

there should be

```
class Student(Person , Teacher):
    def __init__(self,sub,grade,name,fname,lname):
```